# How do I pass a variable to derived class from base class?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to pass down the input values of variables from the base class Watch to the derived class Repair. I have tried to insert getter and setter function inside the Watch class but it doesn't work. Please help!
For example, I insert "antique" as the watch variable but it doesn't pass down to the watch variable inside the Repair class.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<iomanip>

using namespace std;

class Watch
{
protected:
    int price, age;
    string watch;

public:
    void type_watch()
    {
        cout<<"\nHow much is your watch?\n";
        cin>>price;

        cout<<"And, how old is your watch?\n";
        cin>>age;

        if(price>800&&age<=50)
        {
            watch=="designer";
            cout<<"\nYour watch is classified as designer.\n";
        }
        else if(price<=800&&age<=50)
        {
            watch=="non-designer";
            cout<<"\nYour watch is classified as non-designer.\n";
        }
        else
        {
            watch=="antique";
            cout<<"\nYour watch is classified as antique.\n";
        }
    }
};

class Repair:public Watch
{
    string gold_silver, free_repair;
    float repair_price;

public:
    void repair_watch()
    {
       cout<<"\nYour watch is classified as "<<watch<<".\n";

        if(watch=="designer")
        {
            cout<<"Is your watch made of gold or silver?\n";
            cin>>gold_silver;

            if(gold_silver=="gold")
            {
                repair_price=price*(1/4);
            }
            else if(gold_silver=="silver")
            {
                repair_price=price*(1/3);
            }
            else
            {
                cout<<"Sorry, no matches.\n";
                return;
            }
        }
        else if(watch=="non-designer")
        {
            cout<<"Is it on the free repair list?\n";
            cin>>free_repair;

            if(free_repair=="yes")
            {
                repair_price=0;
            }
            else if(free_repair=="no")
            {
                repair_price=price*0.15;
            }
        }
        else if(watch=="antique")
        {
            repair_price=age/2;
        }
    }

    void total_price()
    {
        cout<<"The total cost of repair is $"<<fixed<<setprecision(2)<<repair_price<<".\n";
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    string ans, repair_watch;
    Watch w;
    Repair r;

    cout<<"~~~Welcome to ABC Watches~~~\n\n";
    while(ans!="no")
    {
        cout<<"\nWould you like to classify your watch?\n";
        cin>>ans;

        if(ans=="no")
        {
            cout<<"\nThank you for choosing ABC Watches! Good bye!\n";
        }
        else if(ans=="yes")
        {
            w.type_watch();
            cout<<"\nWould you like to repair your watch?\n";
            cin>>repair_watch;

            if(repair_watch=="yes")
            {
                r.repair_watch();
                r.total_price();
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Seems like an design problem. Should `repair` inherit `watch`? Or just take `watch` as an   input?

Comment: Voting to close as a typo, since your assignments are actually boolean comparisons (whose results are immediately discarded).

Comment: So I used = operator instead of == but still not passing down :( why is it still discarded?

Comment: Repair is an action, something you do to a watch, not a thing unto itself. It probably should not be a class and definitely should not [be a watch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a). Definitely violates the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56860/what-is-an-example-of-the-liskov-substitution-principle).

Comment: `Watch w;` This defines a `Watch` object `w`, but then `Repair r;` defines a `Repair` object `r` which is derived from `Watch`. So `w.type_watch();` gets called for one object, then  `r.repair_watch();` for the other completely different object, whose `Watch` subobject has never been initialized.

Comment: oh I understood thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Summary

1. **You don't need both the `Watch w;` and `Repair r;` variables - just use `r` for everything**
2. **You're not assigning to the variable `watch` - instead you're comparing it using operator==()**

## Comment on design

First of all, I wouldn't recommend using inheritance for this. While it can be done, inheritance is used to model an "x is a y" relationship. In your code, `Repair` inherits from `Watch`, but `Repair` is NOT a `Watch`. I'd recommend looking into some C++ Inheritance tutorials on YouTube for some more details on this.

### Solution to problem

Now for your question... :P

#### ---------- Issue #1 ----------

In your `main()` function, you create two variables: `Watch w;` and `Repair r;`. It is hopefully clear that `w` and `r` do NOT share any memory whatsoever, as they are completely separate variables.

When you call `w.type_watch();`, you store the console input data into `w`. And then when you call `r.repair_watch();` and `r.total_price();`, you access the data stored in `r` (NOT `w` where the data was stored). What ends up happening is that you end up reading empty strings stored in `r`, so you don't get the result you expect.

HOWEVER, there is a simple fix :)

`r` technically contains two components built on top of each other - a `Watch` component and a `Repair` component - because `Repair` inherits from `Watch`. Because of this, `r` contains all variables and functions found within the `Watch` class.

Long story short, **you DON'T need to create an extra `Watch` variable yourself. So get rid of that `Watch w;` variable completely.** Simply substitute `r` in every place where you were using `w`. Your `int main()` function then becomes the following:

```cpp
int main(void)
{
    string ans, repair_watch;
    //Watch w;  <-- REMOVE this variable
    Repair r;

    cout<<"~~~Welcome to ABC Watches~~~\n\n";
    while(ans!="no")
    {
        cout<<"\nWould you like to classify your watch?\n";
        cin>>ans;

        if(ans=="no")
        {
            cout<<"\nThank you for choosing ABC Watches! Good bye!\n";
        }
        else if(ans=="yes")
        {
            r.type_watch();  // <-- Use 'r' variable here
            cout<<"\nWould you like to repair your watch?\n";
            cin>>repair_watch;

            if(repair_watch=="yes")
            {
                r.repair_watch();
                r.total_price();
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

#### ---------- Issue #2 ----------

Finally, you're also using the comparison operator `operator==()` which returns a bool (true/false) instead of assigning to your `watch` variable.

Instead of doing:

```
if(price>800&&age<=50)
{
    watch=="designer";
    cout<<"\nYour watch is classified as designer.\n";
}
```

You should be doing:

```
if(price>800&&age<=50)
{
    watch = "designer";
    cout<<"\nYour watch is classified as designer.\n";
}
```

Comment: Aside: Careful when searching for tutorials. There's a lot of misleading and outright bad material out there, and if you don't already almost know what you're looking for, odds are you won't be able to tell a good tutorial from a bad one. Bit of a catch 22 there.